# Finding route by joining next points

Tags: postgresql, database

I have points data,

e.g. `p1,p5,p3,p6,p7` are the points of **road-A**, while `p2,p4,p8,p9` are point of **road-B**. In database (PostgreSQL) points are in `p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7`...

How can I make a route, by identifying every next point?

*As points in database are not in order of route.*

Comment: You question is not very clear. Do you have a attribute field with the name of the road?

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you use PostgresSQL?

Comment: Yes I have name attribute field. & I am using PostgresSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `Buffer` to limit out the points and then calculated `bearing` between buffer points(coordinates) and saved that in MySQL table. `Nearest Neighbor` and `bearing` gave me next point of road.